# Which one is more SEO friendly Dynamic pages or static pages for blogging website

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing

I am new to web development and I am developing a Blogging website. While working on its architecture from the SEO point of view, I came across a problem that whether I should create a seperate page for each article to read or should I create only one page anrd dynamically pass the article's unique ID to that page to fetch the article from database. Which approach is more SEO friendly ?

Comment: As far as Google is concerned, they are both the same. As long as a particular URL resolves to a particular page, it doesn't matter if the page was built dynamically or statically.

Comment: @StephenCollins You read the OPs question like I did the first time. However, I rather suspect that the OP has something different in mind. You are absolutely right a static page versus a dynamic page makes no difference as long as they are relatively the same thing. However, I read the OPs question as the dynamic page ***not*** returning the article, but rather links to the articles. This would be counter productive if that is what the OP is thinking. Cheers!!